# Are curly braces required in @interface declarations in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, interface, curly-braces

The following code compiles:

```
@interface MyClass : ParentClass // missing {
// missing }
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;
@end
```

I'm wondering if the curly braces in `@interface` declarations are actually necessary.

Comment: Did you get an error when you built with the `{`s removed?

Comment: No compiler errors.  Just seemed odd w/o the braces.

Comment: No, this code will compile fine. But wait, *you said* that!

Comment: I know :-)  I was just curious because it seemed odd.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, the `{ }` section isn’t necessary; your code will compile fine without it. It’s the area where you declare instance variables, and if you’re not doing that, you’re free to leave it out. You don’t even actually need to declare ivars for your properties—the compiler’s smart enough to add them where they’re needed.

Comment: Depends on your compilers warning flags. You may also get an error saying the class struct has no members.

Comment: @Mac Which warning flag? Neither clang 2.1 nor gcc 4.2.1 give warnings with `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: @Bavarious I get warnings in Xcode 4.1 with default settings if I omit the braces.

Comment: @Thu I don’t and I wonder why. In fact, Xcode 4.1’s template for a subclass of `NSObject` doesn’t even have braces in the class declaration.

Comment: Maybe it is a C++-ism, it certainly is not a default behavior in Objective-C to give any such compiler warning.

Answer (score 9):

The compiler is clever enough to add your @property delarations to the class.

The only use for those brackets is when you want to make a variable private, protected or specifically public.

Example:

```
@interface Example: NSObject {
@public
    int publicVar;
@private
    int privateVar;
    int privateVar2;
@protected
    int protectedVar;
}
@end
```

Comment: This is an important piece of info!